# Replacement of QueryString web part in SharePoint Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, query-string

Is there any replacement of QueryString Web Parts in Modern UI? SPFx is the last option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not a OOTB client web part to replacement of QueryString Web Parts in Modern UI, we have to create a custom SPFx web part to achieve it.

The following articles for your reference.

[SPFX obtaining the URL Query Parameters](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/spfx-obtaining-the-url-query-parameters/)

[SharePoint Framework Client-Side Web Part Samples & Tutorial Materials](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts)

Comment: Thanks for your response LZ_MSFT. Unfortunately the first link is not opening. Could you please re-post the same?